# Maximum possible Attack Roll bonus?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, attack-roll

I decided to attempt to figure out what the highest possible bonus to a single attack roll, given the proper magic items and spell buffs. From what I could tell, the best way to go about this would be with a 20th level ranger, given the conditions below:

- 20th Ranger, 20Dex + 20Wis, target is a favored enemy
- +6 profiency bonus
- +5 dexterity ability score modifier
- +5 foe slayer feature
- +3 magic bow
- +3 magic arrow
- +2 archery fighting style
- +1 ioun stone mastery

That gets me to a +25 to hit, but I feel I could still go further...
Say the ranger was to receive a *Bless* spell (1d4) and a *Bardic Inspiration* Die from a 17th or higher Bard (1d12), then proceeded to roll max on both dice and use them for his attack roll, yielding an additional +16 attack roll bonus, that would cap out at a whopping +41 to hit.

That said, given RAW rules regarding ability score caps and attuned magic items, as well as spells and items found in official material only, what other spells, features, magic items, and buffs from other creatures would add to this hypothetical attack roll modifier?

Comment: A clarifying question: do you mean what else could add to your level 20 Ranger's attack? Or do you mean what other classes could get as high (or higher) attack bonuses as this Ranger? Or both?

Comment: @BenBarden Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: @chaoticgeek Comments are also not suitable for working around account privilege restrictions, and in any case, users continually adding new answer material to the question would not be appropriate. If you have a question about or problem with how the site works or is moderated, please feel free to post on [meta]. As how the site works/is moderated is not related to fixing this post, comments here are also not suitable for that. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add expertise as well?

Comment: I've cast the 5th close vote on this -- others were for too broad, so I've voted the same. However I find this in need of clarification of whether we specifically need to enhance that ranger (as Gandalfmeansme asked) or whether we can create any arbitrary different creature or character instead.

Answer (score 2):

Since you added Bless and Bardic Inspiration to your original post if there is also a war domain cleric, presumably the one who cast bless, and is within 30ft of you, has it's reaction, and has uses of channel divinity left that person could use the war domain channel divinity feature to grant a +10 to the attack roll. bringing your new bonus up to a +51 to hit.